# Django Prefetch Related with Filter on Max Value

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, database-performance

We have a pair of models that look (roughly) like this:

```
class Machine(models.Model):
    machine_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    # Other irrelevant fields

    @property
    def latest_update(self):
        if self.machineupdate_set.count() == 0:
            return None
        return self.machineupdate_set.order_by('-update_time')[:1].get()

class MachineUpdate(models.Model):
    machine = models.ForeignKey(Machine)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # Other irrelevant fields
```

Whenever we load `Machine`s from the database, we always end up using the `latest_update` for that machine. When we first implemented this, we had a lot of machines and a fairly small number of updates per machine, so to improve performance (by reducing query count) we added a simple default prefetch to the model manager for `Machine`:

```
class MachineManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(MachineManager, self).get_queryset().prefetch_related('machineupdate_set')
```

However, things have changed and now we have huge numbers of updates related to each machine, and the prefetch query is starting to become a problem (both in terms of long query execution time and memory consumption).

We are looking for a smarter way of pre-fetching the required data, as all we *really* need to pre-fetch is the latest update per machine, not all of them. Having looked at the [Django prefetch_related docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) it looked like we could change `get_queryset` in our `MachineManager` to something like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    latest_update_query = MachineUpdate.objects.order_by('-update_time')[:1]
    latest_update_prefetch = models.Prefetch('machineupdate_set', queryset=latest_update_query, to_attr='_latest_update')
    return super(MachineManager, self).get_queryset().prefetch_related(latest_update_prefetch)
```

and then modify `latest_update` to use the new attribute populated by the pre-fetch. However, this does not work because whenever we filter a `Machine` query using this we get an error: `AssertionError: Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.`

Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem, so that we can efficiently load the `latest_update` for each machine? We are unsure how to fix the issue we have with the above attempt at pre-fetching the latest updates.

(FYI - we have considered adding a `is_latest_update` boolean field to `MachineUpdate` which we can filter on, or alternatively a `latest_update` foreign key reference on `Machine`, however we want to avoid having to maintain this redundant information).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see that `MachineUpdate.update_time` has `auto_now_add=True`. So we can use `Max(MachineUpdate.id)` per `Machine` group to get the last `MachineUpdate`. Right? If that's `True` checkout the following code:

```
class MachineManager(models.Manager):
    pass

class MachineQueryset(models.QuerySet):
    def with_last_machineupdate(self):
        return self.prefetch_related(models.Prefetch('machineupdate_set',
            queryset=MachineUpdate.objects.filter(
                id__in=Machine.objects \
                    .annotate(last_machineupdate_id=models.Max('machineupdate__id')) \
                    .values_list('last_machineupdate_id', flat=True) \
            ),
            #notice the list word
            to_attr='last_machineupdate_list'
        ))


class Machine(models.Model):
    machine_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    objects = MachineManager.from_queryset(MachineQueryset)()

    @property
    def latest_update(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'last_machineupdate_list') and len(self.last_machineupdate_list) > 0:
            return self.last_machineupdate_list[0]
        return None

class MachineUpdate(models.Model):
    machine = models.ForeignKey(Machine)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.update_time)
```

Usage:

```
machines = Machine.objects.filter(...).with_last_machineupdate()
```

If that's not the case, e.g. we can't use `Max('machineupdate__id')` and we need to stick with `update_time` field. Then a slightly more optimized solution (but still getting all `MachineUpdates` per `Machine`) looks like this:

```
class MachineManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(MachineManager, self).get_queryset() \
            .prefetch_related(models.Prefetch('machineupdate_set',
                queryset=MachineUpdate.objects.order_by('-update_time')
            ))

class Machine(models.Model):
    machine_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    objects = MachineManager()

    @property
    def latest_update(self):
        #this will not make queries
        machine_updates = self.machineupdate_set.all()
        if len(machine_updates) > 0:
            return machine_updates[0]
        return None
```

Comment: This worked fantastically - we actually ended up implementing a combination of both you're suggestions, using the `last_machineupdate_list` in objects returned by certain manager queries, and falling back on the more efficient approach you suggested at the end of the answer.

Comment: As my colleague pointed out, we were also able to put `objects = MachineQueryset.as_manager()` into the `Machine` class, removing the need for the empty `MachineManager` class.

Comment: Thank you for posting this detailed example! I have a similar problem and also thought about using `annotate` as an efficient approach to avoid lots of small queries. Your post confirms that this might also be a reasonable solution for my case.